# Image is rendered for all documents instead for one

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have this in my collections for example:

`Document1`

```
title: "doc1",
description: doc1 desc",
image: binary...;
```

`Document2`

```
title: "doc2",
description: doc2 desc";
```

So as you can see I dont have image at all for `Document2`.

This is my HTML code to render image from database:

```
<tr th:each="randomSummerCamps:${randomSummerCamps}">
<div class="title">
    <h1>We think this trip best suit you.</h1>
    <h1 th:text="${randomSummerCamps.title}"></h1>
    <h1 th:text="${randomSummerCamps.state}"></h1>
    <img alt="sample" th:src="*{'data:image/png;base64,'+image}" src=""/>
    <div class="description">
        <td th:text="${randomSummerCamps.description}"></td>
    </div>
    <button type="button" onclick="document.location.href = '/adventureHolidays/getRandomSummerCamps'">Randomize
        again!
    </button>
</div>
```

This is my controller, you can see `model.addAttribute` where I actually render image

```
countSummerCamps.incrementAndGet();
    if (getCountSummerCamps() <= adventureHolidaysService.countAdventureHolidays("summerCamps")) {
        AdventureHolidays photo = adventureHolidaysService.getPhoto();
        model.addAttribute("randomSummerCamps", adventureHolidaysService.findRandomAdventureHolidays("summerCamps"));
        System.out.println("in if");
        model.addAttribute("image",
                Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(photo.getImage().getData()));
        return "randomSummerCamps";
    } else {
        countSummerCamps.set(0);
        return "noMoreDoc";
    }
}
```

And problem is:

Image appear for both documents instead of just for first.
You can see in html that I have `title` and `state` fields and that is rendered good on page, but my picture is showed for both documents. Any idea? Sorry for bad english, and thanks anyone

Comment: You add an image to both documents with `model.addAttribute("image", ...);`. If you don't want that then use an `if` check based on the collection `if(containsImage){model.addAttribute("image", ...);}`

Comment: Sorry, Im trying to fix it with your example but no success. Can you provide me a minimal example